# Autofac Register Generic Delegate factory

Tags: c#, generics, autofac, factory, composite

I am implementing a command handler pattern and i want to create a composite command to solve some use cases. However to achieve this properly i need to resolve a delegate factory as described in http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html. 
However there is an additional complexity, it is generic ... So i assume it must be a generic delegate factory but I am not able to achieve this functionality. It looks complex, but I can not believe this functionality is not available in AutoFac.

I created a gist of my problem with a failing unit test at https://gist.github.com/robvanpamel/2aa2b27da8d0f922b9b98b6331b2e57f.

Is there anybody who could help me out?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xunit;
using Autofac;
namespace Tests
{
public class Tests
{
    public class ClassUnderTest
    {
        public IContainer CreateContainer()
        {
            var builder = new Autofac.ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<MyCommandHandler>().As<ICommandHandler<AnotherCommand>>();
            builder.RegisterType<MyCommandHandler>().As<ICommandHandler<MyCommand>>();
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(CompositeCommandHandler<>)).As(typeof(ICommandHandler<>));

            // How to register this ???  
            //builder.Register<Func<ICommand, ICommandHandler<ICommand>>>(c => s => c.Resolve(s)));

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        // arrange 
        var myClassUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest();
        var container = myClassUnderTest.CreateContainer();
        var myCommand = new MyCompositeCommand(new List<ICommand> { new MyCommand(), new AnotherCommand() });

        // act 
        Assert.IsType<MyCommandHandler>(container.Resolve<ICommandHandler<MyCommand>>());
        Assert.IsType<MyCommandHandler>(container.Resolve<ICommandHandler<AnotherCommand>>());
        var handler = container.Resolve<ICommandHandler<MyCompositeCommand>>();

        handler.Handle(myCommand);
    }
    public interface ICommand { }

    public interface ICompositeCommand : ICommand
    {
        IEnumerable<ICommand> Commands { get; }
    }
    public class MyCommand : ICommand { }
    public class AnotherCommand : ICommand { }
    public class MyCompositeCommand : ICompositeCommand
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<ICommand> commands;
        public MyCompositeCommand(IEnumerable<ICommand> commands)
        {
            this.commands = commands;
        }
        public IEnumerable<ICommand> Commands { get { return commands; } }
    }
    public interface ICommandHandler<T> where T : ICommand
    {
        void Handle(T command);
    }

    public class MyCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<MyCommand>, ICommandHandler<AnotherCommand>
    {
        public void Handle(MyCommand command)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handling MyCommand");
        }

        public void Handle(AnotherCommand command)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handling AnotherCommand");
        }
    }

    public class CompositeCommandHandler<CompositeCommand> : ICommandHandler<CompositeCommand> where CompositeCommand : ICompositeCommand
    {
        private Func<ICommand, ICommandHandler<ICommand>> _factory;
        public CompositeCommandHandler(Func<ICommand, ICommandHandler<ICommand>> factory)
        {
            _factory = factory;
        }

        public void Handle(CompositeCommand command)
        {
            foreach (var myCommand in command.Commands)
            {
                var handler = _factory(myCommand);
                handler.Handle(myCommand);
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

}

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/default-kramer/f8a8a212d94387741eca#file-autofac-genericsource-cs-L290) - I created the poorly-named `GenericSource` to make working with generics a little easier. But I don't know if it still works with the latest version of Autofac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least I have found a sloution for this.

it isn't the best way i suppose but it is running.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xunit;
using Autofac;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Tests
{
public class Tests
{
    public class ClassUnderTest
    {
        public IContainer CreateContainer()
        {
            var builder = new Autofac.ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<MyCommandHandler>().As<ICommandHandler<AnotherCommand>>();
            builder.RegisterType<MyCommandHandler>().As<ICommandHandler<MyCommand>>();
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(CompositeCommandHandler<>)).As(typeof(ICommandHandler<>));

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        // arrange 
        var myClassUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest();
        var container = myClassUnderTest.CreateContainer();
        var myCommand = new MyCompositeCommand(new List<ICommand> { new MyCommand(), new AnotherCommand() });

        // act 
        Assert.IsType<MyCommandHandler>(container.Resolve<ICommandHandler<MyCommand>>());
        Assert.IsType<MyCommandHandler>(container.Resolve<ICommandHandler<AnotherCommand>>());
        var handler = container.Resolve<ICommandHandler<MyCompositeCommand>>();

        handler.Handle(myCommand);
    }
    public interface ICommand { }

    public interface ICompositeCommand : ICommand
    {
        IEnumerable<ICommand> Commands { get; }
    }
    public class MyCommand : ICommand { }
    public class AnotherCommand : ICommand { }
    public class MyCompositeCommand : ICompositeCommand
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<ICommand> commands;
        public MyCompositeCommand(IEnumerable<ICommand> commands)
        {
            this.commands = commands;
        }
        public IEnumerable<ICommand> Commands { get { return commands; } }
    }

    public interface ICommandHandler<in T> where T : ICommand
    {
        void Handle(T command);
    }

    public class MyCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<MyCommand>, ICommandHandler<AnotherCommand>
    {
        public void Handle(MyCommand command)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handling MyCommand");
        }

        public void Handle(AnotherCommand command)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handling AnotherCommand");
        }
    }

    public class CompositeCommandHandler<CompositeCommand> : ICommandHandler<CompositeCommand> where CompositeCommand : ICompositeCommand
    {
        private Func<ICommand, ICommandHandler<ICommand>> _factory;

        private ILifetimeScope _container;
        public CompositeCommandHandler(ILifetimeScope container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public void Handle(CompositeCommand command)
        {

            foreach (var myCommand in command.Commands)
            {
                // resolve the specific command handler
                var handler = ResolveMyHandler(myCommand);

                // invoke the command handler
                var handlerType = handler.GetType();
                var handleMethod = handlerType.GetMethod(nameof(ICommandHandler<ICommand>.Handle),new []{myCommand.GetType()}); 
                handleMethod.Invoke(handler, new[]{ myCommand}); 
            }
        }

        public object ResolveMyHandler(ICommand command)
        {
            var mySpecificHandlerType = command.GetType();
            var myGenericCommandHandlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>);
            var result = myGenericCommandHandlerType.MakeGenericType(new[] { mySpecificHandlerType });
            return _container.Resolve(result);
        }
    }
}
```

}